# Error bn on Google Cloud Storage Nearline

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I get this error when uploading my files/folder into my bucket (free trial).
Some of the transfers work but most fail.

Why?

[image]

Comment: Hi Arone, This is not really something Stack can help you with, as this will require some backend investigation to fix. If you're in free trial, you should have a way to contact support. I believe this would be the proper way to get a solution to your question (I would suggest sending them a HAR file of the error, with a screenshot and timestamp).

Comment: Thanks Patrice. Free trails aren't allowed to open a ticket so I followed the google cloud storage documentation which recommend to ask question on SO. I found a way to contact them so for those who have the same issue cf my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error because my account was disabled (google couldn't verify my billing info). They suspended my account (I could still log in but I couldn't create a bucket or transfert anything) without telling me why, nor sending me an email.

The only way I found to contact them was to click on the " Free trial troubleshooter" link at the top of the email I received as a confirmation for my free trial (just above the banner  -- 1 print "Hello, world!" -- )

They took about 36h to unsuspend my account.